# Ionic2 google maps api error

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to use google map in my Ionic2 application as described [here](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-integrating-google-maps/), however there is a error on `new google.maps.Map` line as follows and so I guess I can not see map on my page:

[image]

[image]

My app.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { App, ionicBootstrap, Platform, Nav, Config } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http } from '@angular/http';
import {AuthHttp, AuthConfig} from 'angular2-jwt';

import { StartPage } from './pages/start/start.component';
import { FarmList } from './pages/farmList/farmList.component';
import { Slider } from './pages/slider/slider.component';
import { ProfilePage } from './pages/profile/profile.component';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  styleUrls: ['/app.scss'],
  providers:[
    provide(AuthHttp, {
      useFactory: (http) => {
        return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig, http);
      },
      deps: [Http]
    })
  ]
})


export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Slider;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any, name: any}>

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [

      { title: 'Start', component: StartPage , name:'home' },
      { title: 'Farms', component: FarmList, name: 'list' },
      { title: 'Profile', component: ProfilePage, name: 'contact' },
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp,[HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

My index.html:

```
<body>

  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- Polyfill needed for platforms without Promise and Collection support -->
  <script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
  <script src="build/js/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="build/js/zone.js"></script>
  <!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
  <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

My component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/start/start.html'
})

export class StartPage {

    map:any

  constructor( private navController: NavController, private platform: Platform) {

    this.initializeMap();
  }

   initializeMap() {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            var minZoomLevel = 12;

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                zoom: minZoomLevel,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

        });
    }   
}
```

My HTML:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Start</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>


<ion-content padding class="page1">

    <div padding>
        <img src="images/icon_transperent.png" width="200"/>
    </div>

    <div id="map_canvas"></div> 

</ion-content>
```

My SCSS:

```
#map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

What exactly is going wrong here?

UPDATE: the complete console screenshot

[image]

## **UPDATE:**

`typings install dt~google.maps --global` must be executed in project directory, otherwise it has no effect!

Comment: Could you please add the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however there is a error on new google.maps.Map line as follows and so
>   I guess I can not see map on my page:

The error you're getting is something like `Cannot find name google`? if so, it's just `typescript` complaining about knowing nothing about a *google* object. That's not an error, your code should be transpiled anyway.

If you don't want to get that *warning* you can install the [definition for google maps](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/googlemaps) (so typescript can be aware of its properties and methods) by executing:

```
typings install google.maps --global
```

Something I would change in your code is:

```
export class StartPage {

  // remove this line, by adding private platform : Platform as a parameter
  // in the constructor already creates an instance of the platform
  // platform : any

  // I've added the private keyword to platform, remember that setting this to
  // public / private is mandatory in the constructor, and by doing that you are
  // creating a variable called platform and asigning it the Platform object by
  // Dependency Injection.
  constructor( private navController: NavController, private platform: Platform) {

    // You don't need this because of what I say in the constructor's comment.
    // this.platform=platform

    this.initializeMap();
  }
```

========================================

EDIT:

About the new error you've just added, I think the issue is because of the Content Security Policy you define in the `index.html`. Let's try adding a very permissive policy which will essentially allow us to load any resources. Depending on your application, you may look into providing a more strict
policy, but an open policy is good for development:

Modify your `www/index.html` file to include the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src * data:; default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

Comment: Are there any npm installs before I even try to use google maps in Ionic? Because once I add these google maps related lines in component, my app stops working.

Comment: it's this: Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys. I will also update my question with my app.ts in a moment

Comment: That's just a warning because you're not using any API key to load the map (you can obtain one here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). But Google Maps works even without an API Key (I'm using it just like you -without an API Key- for an autocomplete component and works fine that way. So the error must be somewhere else...

Comment: I have again updated my question with a error screenshot, however I am not sure if it's the error we are looking for. But actually that's all I can see in my console

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check if that fixs the issue.

Comment: Okay this line removed the error, great! But map still didn't load. See the latest screenshot, looks like there isn't any error and even the div exists on the page. Could it be because using 'atComponent' instead of 'atPage' as he uses in his tutorial?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116443/discussion-between-sebaferreras-and-nitish).

Comment: My mistake: typings install dt~google.maps --global this command had to be executed inside project directory. I t worked! Thanks for such a kind help!

Comment: Great, pleased to hear that! If you don't mind, please add that to your question so other users can be aware of that.

Comment: Sure! I will do that!